# how to do mapping in automapper for classes with complex relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper

```
public class Item
{
  public string Name { get; set; }

  public virtual ICollection<Stock> Stocks { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Price> Prices { get; set; }

  -- remove some code for brevity --
}

public Stock
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int ItemId { get; set; }
  public int StorageId { get; set; }
  public float Amount { get; set; }

  public virtual Item Item { get; set; }
  public virtual Storage Storage { get; set; }

  -- remove some code for brevity --
}

public class Storage
{
  public string Name { get; set; }

  public virtual ICollection<Stock> Stocks { get; set; }

  -- remove some code for brevity --
}

public class SPrice
{
  public decimal Price { get; set; }
  public int decimal ItemId { get; set; }

  public virtual Item Item { get; set; }

  -- remove some code for brevity --
}
```

Above is my POCO classes And I'm just starting out using `Automapper`. I have little complex relationship. I'm confuse on what class is my `source` class and how to do the mapping.

Because what I want to have is only.

- Item Name
- Item Price (recent price)
- Item Stocks (how many stocks the item has in a specific storage, probably a collection?)
- Item Storages (where the item lives, probably a collection?)

For clarity I want them to be displayed as something like this:

```
Name   : Snack bar
Price  : $1.00
Stocks :
         Storages    | How many
         Storage1    | 23
         Storage2    | 24
         Storage3    | 10
```

So far I only have is the `ItemName` and `ItemPrice`that goes like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Item, ItemDTO>()
      .ForMember(dto => dto.Price, opt => 
          opt.MapFrom(s => s.Prices.Any() ? s.Price.OrderByDescending(i => i.Id).FirstOrDefault() : 0m));
```

Then storing them as like this:

```
var items = _itemService.All.Project().To<ItemDTO>();
```

In a nutshell, how to do the mapping for the rest of the property member? Any tips? A demo code would be great. Many thanks!

Comment: Just a sidenote: when the property names of the input and output classes match, you don't have to specify anything but the class mappings (root and leafs). So you could map the Price List and let the client determine which one to display. That would reduce the mapping logic, which I always find more comforting.

Comment: Hello mate. Thanks. I would love to see some sample code since I learn much in demos :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example to add to my comment.

Lets say you have these classes

Model

```
public class Item
{
  public string Name { get; set; }

  public virtual ICollection<Stock> Stocks { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Price> Prices { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel

```
public class ItemViewModel
{
  public string Name { get; set; }

  public StockViewModel [] Stocks { get; set; }
  public PriceViewModel [] Prices { get; set; }
}
```

You just would have to configure the Automapper like so:

```
AutoMapper.CreateMap<Item,ItemViewModel>();
AutoMapper.CreateMap<Stock,StockViewModel>();
AutoMapper.CreateMap<Price,PriceViewModel>();
```

The AutoMapper would then determine the mappings of the subcomposita lists automatically.

Comment: Does this mean you don't need to create classes for `StockViewModel` and `PriceViewModel`?

Comment: You still have to create these. But you don't have to explicitly explain the object structure to the AutoMapper. It is sufficient that the AutoMapper knows the mapping of each composite elements' classes. Basic list and collection mappings are done implicitly.

Comment: Does the order of these configuration matters?

Comment: I don't think so, but somebody else would have to confirm that.